# Method being called before Promise is complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

I am attemting to add an item to a sharepoint list from an Apache Cordova application. It first prompts the user to login then it will make a HTTP Post to so the data entry.

I have the following code:

```
function saveToSharepoint(data) {
    var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
    var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var authResult = authContext.acquireTokenAsync("https://my.sharepoint.com", "4be098f8-2184-4831-9ef7-3d17dbbef6a0", "http://localhost:4400/services/office365/redirectTarget.html")
    .then(FormatAndUpload(authResult, data), errorCallback);

}

function FormatAndUpload(authResponse, data) {
    var token = authResponse.accessToken;
    var expiry = authResponse.expiresOn;
    console.log("Token acquired: " + authResponse.accessToken);
    console.log("Token will expire on: " + authResponse.expiresOn);
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://my.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + Test + "')/items",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Authoriztion":"Bearer " + token
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem I am having is that the FormatAndUpload method is being called before acquireTokenAsync has completed, so the authResponse variable passed into the FormatAndUpload method is null.

I'm not too familiar with the promise framework in Javascript/JQuery but I was under the impression that the event should only fire on completion of the previous method.

Does anyone have any pointers in how I can correctly wait for the login to complete before attempting the POST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you did FormatAndUpload(authResult, data); is wrong
 the correct way to pass a callback is

```
.then(function(authResult){
    FormatAndUpload(authResult, data);
}, errorCallback);
```

so your saveToSharepoint will be like this

```
function saveToSharepoint(data) {
    var authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/";
    var authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
    var authResult = authContext.acquireTokenAsync("https://my.sharepoint.com", "4be098f8-2184-4831-9ef7-3d17dbbef6a0", "http://localhost:4400/services/office365/redirectTarget.html")
    .then(function(authResult){
        FormatAndUpload(authResult, data);
    }, errorCallback);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Newbee Dev, you were correct in that I didn't formulate the then method correctly.

For any others who see this regarding SharePoint, I actually reformatted the code for it to work as expected, so the saveToSharepoint method looks like so:

```
function saveToSharepoint(data) {
var AuthenticationContext = Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext;
AuthenticationContext.createAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/")
    .then(function (authContext) {
        authContext.acquireTokenAsync(
            "https://my.sharepoint.com",     // Resource URI
            "4be098f8-2184-4831-9ef7-3d17dbbef6a0",      // Client ID
            "http://localhost:4400/services/office365/redirectTarget.html"    // Redirect URI
        ).then(function (authResult) {
            FormatAndUpload(authResult, data);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }, function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

The main thing to note is creating the AuthenticationContext asynchronously and this way, the FormatAndUpload calls after the whole login process is complete. Just thought I would post this for other people who see this regarding Sharepoint and are stuck.